# When I would use the "App Root" annotation in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I've read the docs a thousand times but I still don't understand how I would use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root` annotation.

Can someone please provide an example + description in plain english?

Docs: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

I might as well copy paste the entire text; it's not that much.

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root  Defines the Application Root that
> the Controller must redirect if it's in '/' context   string

**App Root**

Create an Ingress rule with a app-root annotation:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /app1
  name: approot
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: approot.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Check the rewrite is working

```
$ curl -I -k http://approot.bar.com/
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.11.10
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 14:57:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Location: http://stickyingress.example.com/app1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 12):

It simply [redirects requests coming to `'/'` to a different path](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite) internally. This is useful if your application's root path is different from `'/'`.

For example, say your application is listening in `'/server'`, you'd set your Nginx annotiations like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /server
```

At this point, any incoming requests at `example.com/` would be [redirected with HTTP status code 302](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64754302/10892354) to indicate where the resource is: `example.com/server`.

Comment: How is this different from the annotation rewrite-target?

Comment: `App Root` is only meant to indicate where the backend is serving requests. There is in fact rewritting in the process. However, `rewrite-target` allows the user, not only to rewrite the root path of the backend, but to determine RegEx groups and set URI order and among other custom rules, so is more a general-purpose/flexible feature.

Comment: How is it different from `path:`  in `spec`?

Answer (score 6):

Using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /destination` annotation will add the following lines the the `nginx.conf`

```
if ($uri = /) {
    return 302 $scheme://$http_host/destination;
}
```

This means that it will instruct the browser to redirect (302 temporarily moved) to the path `/destination`. There is no internal rewrite going on here, as stated by others.

The annotation is very useful if you have a default location that you want to redirect your users to when they hit the root path: `/`